# Rect width exceeds maximum margin (cocos2d-js)

Tags: cocos2d-js

I get this error when I tried to load in a spritesheet

```
    // create sprite sheet
    cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrames(res.ant_walk_plist);
    this.spriteSheet = cc.SpriteBatchNode.create(res.ant_walk_png);
    this.addChild(this.spriteSheet);
```

I used TexturePacker to generate the spritesheet png and plist.

I tried to google the error and someone else mentioned updating cocos2d-js to the latest commit on git and I already did that..

Comment: What line does the error occur? What does it say exactly? Anything else in the log? Have you checked the sprite sheet texture or image size to confirm they are within bounds and within the limits of the hardware (ie max texture size is 4096x4096 pixels, 2048x2048 on older devices like iPhone 4 and iPad 1)

Comment: Error occurs at this line         cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrames(res.ant_walk_plist);

Comment: My texture is very small: 128x256

Comment: I went into cocos2d-js code and found that the error is being printed out from cc.SpriteFrame.cc.Class.extend.initWithTexture at around line 367: if(_x > texture.width){
                cc.log("_x is " + _x + "texture.width is " + texture.width);
                cc.error(cc._LogInfos.RectWidth, texture.url);
            } so I added the print statement and got _x is 120 texture.width is 28.444444444444443

Comment: OK I just realized that in cc.SpriteFrame.cc.Class.extend.initWithTexture the texture size (texture.width and texture.height) is scaled by the contentScaleFactor that I set in cc.director.setContentScaleFactor while the rect size is NOT scaled at all... Am I supposed to tell the sprite manager this number somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hours later I realized that I had files name as "ant@2x_1.png" and "ant@2x_2.png" (naming convention for retina) and somehow this screwed everything up and I don't know why. I just changed the names to "ant_1.png" and "ant_2.png" and everything is fine... JavaScript is always so very pleasant to work with.